# error when downloading any library in thonny

Tags: micropython, lib, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

When I am installing by manage packages I am getting this error every single time:
"Successfully installed picozero-0.4.0
Starting to apply changes to the target.
Copying picozeroError (ManagementError(...), 'Command output was not empty')"
Can someone help me with this.